# ContentResolver in android 2.2 [issue]

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-contentresolver

Am trying to insert an aduio file in the android phone. the same code works fin in android 
2.1

but when i try to use it in Android 2.2; the inserting in ContentResolver succseed but i can't

find my audio file in the gallery (so the user can't see it)

---

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

File k = new File(path, filename);  

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, aud.TITLE);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, aud.MIME_TYPE);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,  aud.ARTIST);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, aud.IS_RINGTONE);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, aud.IS_NOTIFICATION);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, aud.IS_ALARM);  
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, aud.IS_MUSIC);  

//Insert it into the database  
context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: hello,

In fact, that solution works. but i forgot to define 

    (aud.IS_MUSIC=true)

for

    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, aud.IS_MUSIC);   


this sample is useful and may help

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "file:///" that will work

Comment: You should consider expanding your answers to be more informative and grammatically correct. In this one, for example, you could add why you thought that solution would work so that ilredelweb has more of a chance of being able to solve their own problem in the future.

Comment: sorry @Robert Massaioli i am new to stackoverflow i will overcome my faults thank you for correcting my mistakes

Comment: No problems, if that is your attitude then you will do fine. The people with that attitude always end up getting the most rep too because they have great answers. Just look at Don Stewart or John Skeet for examples of what I mean.